# Clojure's -> and ->> macro

Tags: macros, clojure, operators

Clojure's `->>` macro thread the form from the last argument, when `->` form from the first.

```
user=> (->> a (+ 5) (let [a 5]))
10
```

However, I get an exception when I used the operations exchanged.

```
user=> (-> a (let [a 5]) (+ 5))

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: let requires a vector for its binding in user:1, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:7)
```

Furthermore, I expect these two operations will get me the same results, which is not.

```
user=> (-> 0 (Math/cos) (Math/sin))
0.8414709848078965
user=> (->> 0 (Math/sin) (Math/cos))
1.0
```

What's wrong? How's the `->` and `->>` macros work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `->` macro inserts the argument as the first argument for the given function, not giving the argument to the last function. 
Likewise `->>` inserts as the last argument.

```
user=> (macroexpand '(-> x (- 1)))
(- x 1)
user=> (macroexpand '(->> x (- 1)))
(- 1 x)
```

Two simple examples:

```
user=> (-> 1 (- 1) (- 2)) 
-2
user=> (->> 1 (- 1) (- 2))
2
```

As for the first example, `-2 == (- (-  1 1) 2)`, and for the second `2 == (- 2 (-1 1))`

As a result, we get the same results for the unary functions.

```
user=> (macroexpand '(-> 0 Math/sin Math/cos))
(. Math cos (clojure.core/-> 0 Math/sin))
user=> (macroexpand '(->> 0 Math/sin Math/cos))
(. Math cos (clojure.core/->> 0 Math/sin))
```

So, only `->>` makes sense in the question.

```
user=> (macroexpand '(->> a (+ 5) (let [a 5])))
(let* [a 5] (clojure.core/->> a (+ 5)))
user=> (macroexpand '(-> a (+ 5) (let [a 5])))

IllegalArgumentException let requires a vector for its binding in user:1  clojure.core/let (core.clj:4043)
```

Comment: ... and both `->` and `->>` apply their argument forms left to right, so that `(-> 0 (Math/cos) (Math/sin))` does the same as `(->> 0 (Math/cos) (Math/sin))`, not `(->> (Math/sin) (Math/cos))`